# Move child product category to parent api

Tags: magento2, category, rest-api

I'm using Magento 2.2 REST api to create and update product category.
To change product category parent I use following url and request body and it works fine.

```
HTTP method: PUT
url: rest/V1/categories/153/move
request body : {"parent_id":337,"afterId":0}
```

But I want to change child category to parent category, then I tried to send following request body and it gives the following error.

```
HTTP method: PUT
url: rest/V1/categories/153/move
request body: {"parent_id":0"afterId":0}
error: "error :{"message":"Decoding error."}"
```

Please help to make the correct request for change child category to parent category.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your request parameters
It should be-

```
request body: {"parent_id":0, "afterId":0}
```